# ID только что вставленной записи

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Пытаюсь получить **ID** только что вставленной записи. Испробовал такие варианты:
Для проверки результата вывожу этот **ID** в **ShowMessage**.
1)

```
 DM.Query1.SQL.Clear;  
 DM.Query1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO myTable (pole1, pole2) VALUES ("'+sEdit1.Text+'", "'+sEdit2.Text+'"); select @@IDENTITY as ident');  
 DM.Query1.ExecSQL;
 ShowMessage(DM.Query1.FieldValues['ident'].AsInteger);
```

2)

```
DM.Query1.SQL.Clear;  
DM.Query1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO myTable (pole1, pole2) VALUES ("'+sEdit1.Text+'", "'+sEdit2.Text+'"); SET @lastID := LAST_INSERT_ID()');  
DM.Query1.ExecSQL;  
ShowMessage(DM.Query1.FieldValues['@lastID'].AsInteger);
```

Не могу понять, где ошибка. Как правильно делать?

Comment: А какого типа компонент Query1 и какая СУБД Microsoft или MySQL?

ShowMessage(DM.Query1.Fields[0].**AsString**);





Comment: ADOQuery и Access2010, если вы это имели в виду.
ShowMessage(DM.Query1.Fields[0].AsString);  -  применимо к обоим вариантам? Они оба правильные?

Comment: Пишет "Обнаружены символы за пределами инструкции SQL" при 1-м варианте, а при 2-м "Неправильно определен объект Parameter"

Answer (score 1):

1. Для компонент ADO следующий код правильный:

   ```
   ShowMessage(DM.Query1.Fields[0].AsString);
   ```
2. В MS Access нет возможности писать в запросе более чем одну команду.
3. В MS Access нет переменной  `@@IDENTITY` и функции `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.
4. В тексте Query1.SQL нельзя использовать двойную кавычку. Нужно писать так

   ```
   DM.Query1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO myTable (pole1, pole2) VALUES ('''+sEdit1.Text+''', '''+sEdit2.Text+''')');
   ```

Работающий, но ненадежный вариант для MS Access:

```
DM.Query1.SQL.Clear;  
 DM.Query1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO myTable (pole1, pole2) VALUES ('''+sEdit1.Text+''', '''+sEdit2.Text+''')');  
 DM.Query1.ExecSQL;
DM.Query1.Close;
 DM.Query1.SQL.Text:='select max(id) from myTable ';
 DM.Query1.Open;
 ShowMessage(DM.Query1.Fields[0].AsString);
```

Comment: Все пункты понял, взял во внимание. Спасибо! А на счёт моей задачи. Как её можно решить?

Comment: дописал выше

Comment: Код __DM.Query1.SQL.Text:='select max(id) from myTable ';__ не работает

Comment: Для ответа на вопрос нужно:
1) предоставить определение таблицы с описанием имен и типов полей; 
2) исходный код;
3) желательно текст ошибки и номер строки, на которой она возникает.

Comment: Код __DM.Query1.SQL.Text:='select max(id) from myTable ';__ работает только если при двойном клике на элементе __Query1__ не были добавлены все поля в открывшемся окне. Иначе он не может найти __"Query1: Field 'ID' not found"__. Почему так?